# How do I render reach native components properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, native, tic-tac-toe

I have a tic tac toe game I am making. After each round, I want to switch who goes first. If the user went first in round 1 the CPU will go first in round 2 and continue on. In my restart method, after there is a tie, won or loss,

```js
startOver = () => {
    this.totalTurns = 0;
    this.gameOver = false;

    const newBoard = [
      ["", "", ""],
      ["", "", ""],
      ["", "", ""],
    ];

    this.setState({
      board: newBoard,
      gameOverScreen: false,
      whoWon: "",
    });

    // every time the user goes
    //turn is changed to 1 so the cpu can goo
    // i want to keep this value alternating
    if (this.turn === 1) {
      this.cpuTurn();
    }
  };
```

The problem is that the board is not clearing after this. My board is basically 9 elements of touchable opacity with a child text component which changes when you touch it.

```html
 <TouchableOpacity style={styles.container}
  onPress={() => this.pressed({ row: 2, column: 1 })}>
  
    <Text style={styles.value}>{this.state.board[2][1]}</Text>

</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Turn and newboard must be a state to maintain persistence.

Answer (score 1):

So my programming logic was wrong. Every time the user picks a position, turn=1, so the CPU can go, and after the CPU goes turn=0 so the user can go. Each game, I wanted to switch who went first, that was what I wanted to do. Trying to use the turn variable to accomplish that was a mistake, so I made a new variable **whoGoesFirst**, and it changes only after the game is restarted. I also found out that setState is asynchronous, so I manually changed the **board**  as shown below, so the cpuTurn can use a blank board, instead of the current board.

```js
this.state.board = newBoard;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import React, { Component } from "react";  
class Logic extends Component {  
constructor(){  
    this.state={  
    TotalTurns:0,  
    gameOver :false,  
    newBoard :[  
    ["", "", ""],  
    ["", "", ""],  
    ["", "", ""],  
    ],  
    turn:0,  
    }  

startOver(){  
    var Turn=this.state.turn;  
    if (Turn==1){  
    this.cpuTurn();  
    }  
}  

cpuTurn(){  
}   

render() {
    return ( 
    <div>  
    GAME:  
    {this.state.newBoard}  
    </div>  
        );  
        }  
            }
```

Comment: Thanks this helps makes my code a lot cleaner, but I just solved my problem